# Memory leakage issue on IOS when using xcode profiler

Tags: c++, ios, assembly, memory-management, xcode7

when we are running code using xcode profiler then we can see memory leak in few function but when we went through the code everything is fine like memory allocation and deallocation.Assembly generated by the xcode profile and compiler generated assembly is not matching...due to which we are getting memory leakage problems.

Comment: a) When using Instruments, you usually inspect the _optimized_ output (build configuration "Release"). When you say the "generated assembly" is not matching, you might be comparing a "Release" build with a "Debug" build. b) Instruments is usually not lying when it says there's a leak. Most likely, there really is. The question is how _severe_ the leak is. c) Without your code we can't help you except by making high-level guesses.

Comment: Did you respect the [Naming convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)? 99% of the times ut's an issue with (understaing) *ARC* rather than an "assembly" problem. However without the code, it's just a guess.